# Split a variable in javascript getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery

I have a QR scanner decoded data as shown below

```
http:\\14.147.140.93:8080\......\json={
    "location": "122121212",
    "screen": "4545458",
    "identification": "333"
}
```

From the above variable i am trying to fetch the JSON value that is

```
{
    "location": "122121212",
    "screen": "4545458",
    "identification": "333"
}
```

I tried this way

```
var data = 
    'http:\\14.147.140.93:8080\......\json={
    "location": "122121212",
    "screen": "4545458",
    "identification": "ddddd"
}';

function call()
{

    var name = data.split('{');
      var url = name[0];
     var json = name[1];

    alert(json);

}

call();
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5GRdC/

But i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  in browser console .

could anybody please help me ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5GRdC/7/

Comment: This is a silly question TBH but here's a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/27MNj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are having `\n` newLine entries in your data try to get in this format.

```
var data = 'http:\\14.147.140.93:8080\......\json={"location": "122121212","screen": "4545458","identification": "ddddd"}';
```

Comment: to get your data in this format you could use sth. like .replace("\n","")